# How does one determine what ARL0 should be used on CPM package to test for Structural Change

Tags: r, time-series, structural-change

I'm trying to find multiple break points by using `processStream` from `CPM` package on R.
Can someone enlighten me on what is `ARL0` how does one determine what `ARL0` should be used for?

```
processStream(ret.fin.chn,"Kolmogorov-Smirnov",ARL0=500,lambda=NA)
$changePoints
    [1]   59   75  250  286  443  448  663 1037 1042 1261 1576 1842 1853 2013 2035 2621 2633
    $detectionTimes
[1]   73   89  285  334  447  503  670 1040 1145 1428 1639 1951 1874 2030 2078 2632 2644
```

while

```
processStream(ret.fin.chn,"Kolmogorov-Smirnov",ARL0=2000,lambda=NA)
$changePoints
    [1]   59   75  663 1037 1261 1559 1842 2013 2035 2621 2633
    $detectionTimes
[1]   75   90  691 1041 1480 1688 2026 2032 2266 2633 2646
```

and

```
processStream(ret.fin.chn,"Kolmogorov-Smirnov",ARL0=3000,lambda=NA)
$changePoints
    [1]   59   75  663 1037 1261 1559 1842 2013 2149
    $detectionTimes
[1]   75   92  692 1041 1490 1690 2026 2032 2284
```

Tt seems that different `ARL0` will give fewer break point detection, is that a good thing?

**Note**: the time series `ret.fin.chn` contains 2749 rows.

Below are excerpts from `R` help:

> ARL0
>
> Determines the `ARL_0` which the CPM should have, which corresponds to the average number of observations before a false positive occurs, assuming that the sequence does not undergo a chang. Because the thresholds of the CPM are computationally expensive to estimate, the package contains pre-computed values of the thresholds corresponding to several common values of the `ARL_0`. This means that only certain values for the `ARL_0` are allowed. Specifically, the `ARL_0` must have one of the following values: 370, 500, 600, 700, ..., 1000, 2000, 3000, ..., 10000, 20000, ..., 50000

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, apparently the $ARL0=\frac1\alpha$ where alpha is ***false alarm probability***

a further reading wold be

> Nonparametric monitoring of data streams for changes in location and scale
>   GJ Ross, DK Tasoulis, NM Adams - Technometrics, 2011 - Taylor & Francis